# Esperar a que termine dispatch Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Cuando intento iniciar sesión o recuperar la autenticación, la vista se muestra primero antes de finalizar la promesa, he intentado con await, pero dispatch no me permite
Necesito esperar a que termine el dispatch para continuar

Muestro el ejemplo de código para ver dónde está el error.
No soy muy hábil, estoy estudiando y aprendiendo.
Gracias de antemano a todos por su ayuda.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
//const
const dataInitial = {
    isLogin: false,
    userToken: null,
    user: null,
    message: { text: '', type: '' },
};

//Type
const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';

//reducer
export default function loginReducer(state = dataInitial, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
 case LOGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload.user,
                userToken: action.payload.token,
                message: action.payload.message,
                isLogin:true,
            };
default:
            return state;

}

//actions
export const loginInAction = (credentials) => async (dispatch, getState, setState) => {
    let fail = false
    getState.isLoading = true
    const url = `${serverBaseUrl}/auth/login`;
    await axios
        .post(url, credentials)
        .then(async (response) => {
            const result = response.data;
            const { message, token, user } = result;

            if (message == 'success') {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token).then(()=>{
                    dispatch({
                        type: LOGIN,
                        payload: {
                            token: token,
                            user: JSON.stringify(user),
                            message: { text: '', type: '' },
                        },
                    });
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    fail = true
                    /**@todo Send Error API */
                });
                
            } else {
                fail = true
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            fail = true
            /**@todo Send Error API */
        });
    if (fail) {
        dispatch({
            type: MESSAGE,
            payload: {
                message: { text : "Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto", type : 'FAILS' },
            },
        });
    }


};
```

llamando al reducer

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { loginIsAction } from './../redux/loginDuck';
const checkLoginCredentials = async (credentials) => {
    dispatch(loginInAction (credentials));
    setAppReady(true);
  };
```

lo que necesito es que se quede la vista de Loading mientras se esta ejecutando el metodo y en caso de fallar se muestre el message
Expo - react-native

Comment: Utilizó la metodología Duck Para el Reducer, me parece mas comodo

Comment: sé que no debo utilizar await cuando tengo un then, es que he probado varias soluciones tampoco funciona dispatch(loginInAction (credentials)()) realizando una llama a la segunda función,

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que tienes que usar `useState` y `useEffect` de react en el punto mas alto antes de renderizar tu aplicación, por ejemplo:

`checking`: variable para identificar si la aplicación esta verificando la autenticación.

`isLogged`: determina si el usuario esta logeado.

En este caso, cuando la variable `cheking` sea = `true` va a renderizar un `h1` con el mensaje:`Espere...`. y no va a continuar hasta que la variable `isLogged` sea true y setCheking pase a ser `false` para permitir renderizar los demás componentes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Escuchar una variable que determine si estas logeado(isLogged).

    if (isLogged) {
      setChecking(false);
    }
  }, [setChecking]);

  if (checking) {
    return <h1>Espere...</h1>;
  }

  return <div>Bienvenido...</div>;
```